# How to disable getting only meta data in route OData

Tags: routes, odata, prefix

I added two routes. One of them contains dynamic prefix:

```
ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        builder.EntityType<UOM>();
        var entityType = builder.EntityType<Product>();
        builder.EntitySet<Product>("Products");
        builder.EntitySet<UOM>("UOMs");

        var model = builder.GetEdmModel();
        config.MapODataServiceRoute(
        routeName: "ODataRoute",
        routePrefix: null,
        model: model);

        config.MapODataServiceRoute(
        routeName: "ODataRouteWithContext",
        routePrefix: "{context}/",
        model: model);
```

Now when I send https://localhost:44326/ I will get metadata :

[image: result]

But when I try something like https://localhost:44326/xyz it will return metadata too.

The purpose of the second route is to get entities from specific context. For example, https://localhost:44326/ac2db7f3-7581-4e6a-afa0-c4548d6ae89a/Products 
So, context prefix should be only Guid type. But I don't want to show metadata for https://localhost:44326/xyz requests. So how can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added custom convention in route and ignored showing metadata like this:

```
conventionsWithContextTokenPrefix.Except(conventionsWithContextTokenPrefix.OfType<MetadataRoutingConvention>())
```